# Laravel hasMany when parent doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Parent.php**

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Child');
    }
}
```

and I used this in my controller:

```
$children = Parent::find($parent_id)->children;
```

and it's OK when `$parent_id` exist. But when $parent_id` doesn't exist. it returns this error:

```
Trying to get property 'children' of non-object
```

What is the solution to prevent this error or return a false?

Comment: yes,simply put if condition before you assign parent  to children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simple:

```
<?php
$children = null;
$parent = Parent::find($parent_id);
if ($parent) {
   $children = $parent->children;
}
return $children; // or return false, or throw Exception - whatever you like
```

The above would return a `HasMany` relation if the parent exists, or false if it doesn't. 
If you need a collection regardless - a better way would be to do it another way round, like this:

```
<?php
$children = Children::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->find();
return $children;
```

Answer (score 1):

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;`

`$parent = Parent::find($parent_id)`

`$chilren = is_null($parent) ? Collection::make([]) : $parent->children;` This is the first solution

You check if the parent is not null then use has many relation or return empty eloquent collection

or you can  get children by parent id

`Child::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->get()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$childData=''; 
$parentdata = Appuser::find($parent_id);
if(isset($parentdata)){
$childData = $parentdata->order;
}
 return $childData;
```